# NextJS 13 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'primary')

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, next.js13

im currently following a tutorial and I tried this code before in nextjs 12 and it works perfectly fine. now im trying this code in nextjs 13 and im getting an error and i don't really get why im getting this error. the tutorial uses nextjs 12 and @mui/styles but since @mui/styles is now a legacy version im now using @mui/system. i've tried completing the whole tutorial in nextjs 12 but i just keep getting vulnerabilities and errors so im now trying it on nextjs 13

this is the code

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/system';
import {
  AppBar,
  Box,
  Container,
  CssBaseline,
  Link,
  ThemeProvider,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
} from '@mui/material';
import Head from 'next/head';
import NextLink from 'next/link';
import classes from '../utils/classes';

export default function Layout({ title, description, children }) {
  const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
      MuiLink: {
        defaultProps: {
          underline: 'hover',
        },
      },
    },
    typography: {
      h1: {
        fontSize: '1.6rem',
        fontWeight: 400,
        margin: '1rem 0',
      },
      h2: {
        fontSize: '1.4rem',
        fontWeight: 400,
        margin: '1rem 0',
      },
    },
    palette: {
      mode: 'light',
      primary: {
        main: '#f0c000',
      },
      secondary: {
        main: '#208080',
      },
    },
  });
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{title ? `${title} - My App` : 'My App'}</title>
        {description && <meta name="description" content={description}></meta>}
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar position="static" sx={classes.appbar}>
          <Toolbar sx={classes.toolbar}>
            <NextLink href="/" passHref>
              <Link>
                <Typography sx={classes.brand}>My App</Typography>
              </Link>
            </NextLink>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Container component="main" sx={classes.main}>
          {children}
        </Container>
        <Box component="footer" sx={classes.footer}>
          <Typography>All rights reserved. My App.</Typography>
        </Box>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

this is the error
[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

It seems like using

`import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';`

instead of

`import { createTheme } from '@mui/system';`

fixes the error.